# How to solve this Typescript type problem in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement the data type returned from the API I'm using. The `total_page` and `total_results` are marked as an error. Looks like I need to implement some type. I can't understand how to solve this problem this type requirement. The message is:

> (property) React.ProviderProps.value: MoviesContextData
> The type '{ movies: MovieData[]; pageNumber: number; setPageNumber: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; }' does not have the following properties of type 'MoviesContextData': total_pages, total_results ts(2739)
> index.d.ts(327, 9): The expected type comes from the 'value' property, which is declared here in the type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps'"

```
import {
    useContext,
    createContext,
    useEffect,
    useState
} from "react"

import { MoviesProviderProps } from "../interfaces/props"
import { MovieData, MoviesContextData } from "../interfaces/types"

import axios from "axios"
import { POPULAR_BASE_URL } from "../services/api"

const MoviesContext = createContext<MoviesContextData>(
    {} as MoviesContextData
)

export const MoviesProvider = ({ children }: MoviesProviderProps) => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieData[]>([])
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)
    const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0)
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

    const nextPage = ({ pageNumber }: MoviesContextData) => {
       axios.get(`${POPULAR_BASE_URL}&page=${pageNumber}`)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`${POPULAR_BASE_URL}&page=${pageNumber}`)
            .then(response => {
                setMovies(response.data.results)
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <MoviesContext.Provider value={{ movies, pageNumber, setPageNumber }}>
            {children}
        </MoviesContext.Provider>
    )

}

export const useMovies = () => {
    const context = useContext(MoviesContext)

    return context
}
```

Types:

```
  export type MoviesContextData = {
    movies: MovieData[];
    pageNumber: number;
    setPageNumber: (prevState: number) => void;
    total_pages: number;
    total_results: number;
}

export type MovieData = {
    id: number;
    backdrop_path: string;
    poster_path: string;
    title: string;
    release_date: string;
    vote_average: number;
}
```

Comment: Your `value` is incorrect, `value={{ movies, pageNumber, setPageNumber }}` compared to the type you've specified (more details in the answer below). But you should be very careful when writing out a context value this way. You are effectively creating a new object on every render of this parent. Which then means that any child will also re-render. Can be a noticeable performance issue. Maybe look at memoizing this object before passing it as a value `const value = useMemo(() => ({...}), [...])`

Comment: I find it strange that you use two different naming semantics for your variables inside `MoviesContextData`. Why use `camelCase` and `snake_case` in a model you can control?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you meant.

Comment: I used it this way because the data is exactly like this in the API

Comment: What I mean is the MovieData that you get from the API is understandable. But you're creating the context and passing `total_pages` and `pageNumber` through. It would be better to be consistent in your casing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `MoviesContextData` as:

```
export type MoviesContextData = {
    movies: MovieData[];
    pageNumber: number;
    setPageNumber: (prevState: number) => void;
    total_pages: number;
    total_results: number;
}
```

And then you provide this value for that type:

```
<MoviesContext.Provider value={{ movies, pageNumber, setPageNumber }}>
```

`total_pages` and `total_results` are required properties, but are missing in the context provider's value.

That's what this portion of that error message is trying to tell you:

> does not have the following properties of type 'MoviesContextData': total_pages, total_results ts(2739)

---

To fix it you need to provide those properties with something like:

```
<MoviesContext.Provider value={{
  movies,
  pageNumber,
  setPageNumber,
  total_pages: Math.ceil(totalResults / numberOfResultsPerPage),
  total_results: totalResults
}}>
```

Or make the properties optional:

```
export type MoviesContextData = {
    // other properties...
    total_pages?: number;
    total_results?: number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I add these two properties in the context provider, an error appears asking to initialize. What does that mean? This appears here: "There is no in-scope value for the shorthand property 'total_pages'. Declare one or provide an initializer."

Comment: `{ movies }` is shorthand for `{ "movies": movies }` and only works if you have a local variable named `movies`. So you have to provide a for those property names in the context value. I don't know how you system would tell you the total pages, I just guessed with some made up math. You are going to figure out how to provide those values.

Comment: Alex, do you mean that the correct thing would be for me to put the type 'MoviesContextData' in all states related to that type? So I would put the state value as the value of the respective variable that is in the context provider?

Comment: What I mean is that when you have context declared with the type `MoviesContextData`, then you have to use a `value` for that context that is an object that fully implements the `MoviesContextData` type. And that means that it has all required properties from that type.